# How to save database table in text file? And how to specify format in text file?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a script for saving a database table in **.txt** file. The script is working perfectly.The table fields are like this :

```
8,c.s.e,computer ,9,0
9,m.c.a,b.a. in hindi ,10,0
```

but i want it to be like this-:

```
{ "table_name": [
["8","c.s.e","computer","9","0"],
["9","m.c.a","computer","10","0"],
  ]
}
```

and here is my script:

```
    $fh = fopen('db.txt', 'w');
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("dot", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class_master");   
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {          
    $num = mysql_num_fields($result) ;    
    $last = $num - 1;
    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {            
        fwrite($fh, $row[$i]);                       
        if ($i != $last) {
            fwrite($fh, ",");
        }
    }                                                                 
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: collect data in array, then use json_encode($array), after that save that result in file. That's it. But you have to do it with your own.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this line in your code

```
fwrite($fh, json_encode($row[$i]));
```